# Network not detected, but internet working

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, 64-bit

I am using a brand new HP computer with  Windows 7 64 bit.  When I first hooked it up it detected my network (hooked up through ethernet) easily. However, after  I uninstalled Norton Internet Security, it stopped being able to detect my  home network. I can still use the internet as if connected, but I can't go into the network options to communicate with other computers. I had this same problem  on Windows Vista on my previous computer. Is there any way to fix this so it detects the network?

Comment: Your first problem is using Norton. Might I suggest [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/products/security-essentials)?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue with Norton's Network security overriding the windows network and firewall settings. You could try to use [this workaround](http://community.norton.com/t5/Norton-Internet-Security-Norton/Windows-7-Homegroup-Sharing-with-NIS-2011/td-p/404212), or find some information [here](https://www-secure.symantec.com/norton-support/jsp/help-solutions.jsp?lg=english&ct=united+states&docid=v9802256_NAV_Retail_2012_en_us&product=home&version=1&pvid=f-home),
or, like I said in my comment, try using [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/products/security-essentials). It's a free, and very unproblematic, unobtrusive antivirus.

Comment: I installed Microsoft Security Essentials. I'm looking into the workaround. Thank you very much.  And as a note, the problem occurred after I un-installed Norton.   I refuse to use Norton, but it came packaged with my computer.

Comment: I'm not finding a way to get it to detect my home network yet.  Norton is completely removed, and I have a feeling that it removed something important that it should not have when it was installed. More reasons to hate Norton.